# Deployment of api created in lumen at aws server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, lumen

I deploy the project in my regular routine but this time while deploying at aws facing some errors. I deployed there using the ssh command and a key pair at ubuntu 16.04. I installed lamp, PHP, and PHPMyAdmin there successfully.

This is the link and error I am facing http://52.60.197.219/api/category, it says error 404 not found
I tried almost all solutions available but no luck.

Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

my.htaccess file `
    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ Api_load.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

`

my index.php file named as Api_load.php `$app = require __DIR__.'/api/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->run();`

structure of a deployed application
API(folder contains all files and codes)
.htaccess,
Api_load.php

Comment: check that Apache rewrite mode is on or not

Comment: Its already enabled !
any other suggestions please ?

Comment: directory permission must be 777

Comment: everything else is accessible but only the public folder which contains .htaccess and index.php can not be accessed. 52.60.197.219/api/public/category

api is folder name containing all code

Comment: which lumen version you are using? and which php version in your server?
Also check apache error log.

Comment: lumen version is 5.6 and php version i develop code in is 7.2 ..

Comment: i checked error log and it says

 syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/api/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/FlattenException.php on line 41

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177338/discussion-between-usama-shoukat-and-kaushik-andani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , its a common error. its all because of conflicting .htaccess file. 
Follow these steps. 
1)Create Zip of your folder and unzip into the directory you are going to deploy your code.
2)Edit you .env file according to your requirements i.e changing Db username,password and database name.
3).htaccess file and index file in public folder, bring them to the outside of the root directory.
4)now access your baseUrl/endpoint name.
it will work.

Comment: OKay let me try !

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve your problem by adding the config below to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `site-avaliable/000-default.conf`, then restart apache2.

```
<Directory /home/away/workspace/park/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: thanks but still, it says cant find this in server !!
below is the link
http://52.60.197.219/api/public/category